# Getting duplicate images when reloading with stage.toJSON() in kinetic js

Tags: javascript, image, html, html5-canvas, kineticjs

My canvas has few images that are resizable and support drag and drop.

after saving the canvas I'm doing a

```
    var stage = Kinetic.Node.create(json, 'container');
```

If I just add a single image on canvas it is coming fine.
but if I add more than 1 I get multiple images .
like if I add 2 different images I'm getting 4 images 2 each.
if I add 3 I get 3.and so on.

here is a little snippet

```
   var stage = Kinetic.Node.create(json, 'container');
   var images = stage.get('.image');
   console.log(images)
```

In console.log I'm getting multiple json results of a same image.
Rest Im just using src to load the images

```
   for(i=0;i<images.length;i++)
   {  
   //function to induce scope
   (function() {
   var image = images[i];

   console.log(images[i])
  var width = images[i].attrs.width;
  var height = images[i].attrs.height; 
  var imageObj = new Image();
  imageObj.onload = function() {
      image.setImage(imageObj);
       image.getLayer().draw();
    };
  imageObj.src = image.attrs.src;
  })();
 }
```

ANyone knows why this is happening?

Comment: need to see more code

Comment: Same as EliteOctagon--need to see more code.  But since your for-loop is doing set+draw for *every* image in your images[] array, it looks like the for-loop is mistakenly being called every time you add a new image.

Comment: actually the code is too big..SO don't know what to add and what not..everything is inter related. and I'm getting multiple images in the json itself..even before the for loop..So the problem should be where I'm saving the images and doing stage.toJSON()??